# How do I identify the original caller of a method?

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, ide

In most IDEs, you can jump to the implementation of a method by only pressing `ctrl` and click on it, for instance, if I want to see the implementation of `method()` from `X.method();`. My question is: What if I want to do the reverse! In other word, from the method signature, is there a way to identify the original caller?

The reason of this question is because I am currently studying a huge project that includes too many classes and packages and sometimes I want to track back the original caller of a specific method.

Thank you

Comment: On eclipse, right clicking to the method and clicking "Open Call Hierarchy" does the job.

Comment: Besides the "call hierarchy" you can also do a workspace search for references to a class, method, constructor in eclipse. I assume that any decent IDE offers such search capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Find Usages and Method Options in [intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/find-usages-method-options.html?origin=old_help) use:
Alt+F7

This display a menu and there  select **usages**

> Usages - if this check box is selected, the search is performed for
>   all references of the method by its name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    void callee() {
        StackTraceElement s = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1];
        System.out.println(s.getClassName() + " " + s.getMethodName());
    }
```

This will print class name and method name of caller.